# Identify and extract OHLC pattern on candlestick chart using plotly or pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, finance, candlestick-chart

I'm using the Ameritrade API and pandas/plotly to chart a simple stock price on the minute scale, I'd like to use some of the properties of the produced chart to identify and extract a specific candlestick pattern.

Here I build my dataframe and plot it as a candlestick:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'open': pd.json_normalize(df, 'candles').open,
                     'high': pd.json_normalize(df, 'candles').high,
                     'low': pd.json_normalize(df, 'candles').low,
                     'close': pd.json_normalize(df, 'candles').close,
                     'datetime': pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(pd.json_normalize(df, 'candles').datetime, unit='ms')).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')})


fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=frame['datetime'],
                                    open=frame['open'],
                                    high=frame['high'],
                                    low=frame['low'],
                                    close=frame['close'])])
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

[The plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrWaK.png):

The pattern I'm searching for is simply the very first set in each day's trading of four consecutive red candles.

A red candle can be defined as:

`close < open & close < prev.close`

So in this case, I don't have access to `prev.close` for the very first minute of trading because I don't have pre-market/extended hours data.

I'm wondering if it's even possible to access the plotly figure data, because if so, I could just extract the first set of four consecutive `red` candles, and their data - but if not, I would just define my pattern and extract it using pandas but haven't gotten that far yet.

Would this be easier to do using plotly or pandas, and what would a simple implementation look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about `Candlestick`, but in pandas, you could try something like this. *Note: I assume the data have 1 row for each business day already and is sorted.* The first thing is to create a column named red with True where the condition for a red candle as described in you question is True:

```
df['red'] = df['close'].lt(df['open'])&df['close'].lt(df['close'].shift())
```

Then you want to see if it happens 4 days in a row and assuming the data is sorted ascending (usually), the idea is to reverse the dataframe with [::-1], use `rolling` with a window of 4, `sum` the column red created just above and check where it is equal to 4.

```
df['next_4days_red'] = df[::-1].rolling(4)['red'].sum().eq(4)
```

then if you want the days that are at the beginning of 4 consecutive red trading days you do `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['next_4days_red'], 'datetime'].tolist()
```

Here with a little example with dummy varaibles:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'close': [10,12,11,10,9,8,7,10,9,10], 
                   'datetime':pd.bdate_range('2020-04-01', periods=10 )})\
       .assign(open=lambda x: x['close']+0.5)
df['red'] = df['close'].lt(df['open'])&df['close'].lt(df['close'].shift())
df['next_4days_red'] = df[::-1].rolling(4)['red'].sum().eq(4)

print (df.loc[df['next_4days_red'], 'datetime'].tolist())
[Timestamp('2020-04-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-04-06 00:00:00')]
```

Note: it catches two successive dates because it is a 5 days consecutive decrease, not sure if in this case you wanted the two dates

Comment: Thanks for this, and to your assumption, the dataframe has a row for every minute of the trading day because I need to analyze each 1-minute candlestick - so in your example I can just convert the days to minutes, except (I think) where I'd want to isolate the times (rows in the dataframe) during the day where the first four consecutive red candles appear. I'm using the plotly figure to visually inspect if the results are correct and it's not lining up for some reason

Comment: @orion si yes if your data has a row per minutes and you want 4 consecutive minutes red it should be the same idea! and you want only the first time (if any) for each day where it decreases 4 minutes in a row? and what do you mean it does not align?

Comment: @orion after some test, it seems that a candlestick is red when only the condition `close<open` is met, the other one `close < prev.close` is not mandatory?

Comment: @Ben-t - it's hard to show in the comments section let me try! Here's the visual representation of a particular day (https://imgur.com/xPE51Pj), these are the first four red candles in the day and they occur at 11:41-44, I've exported the dataframe (here https://www.dropbox.com/s/3m0vrc3kh3638cy/data.csv?dl=0) and can see the results of the `df.loc[df['next_4days_red'], 'datetime'].tolist())` showing the first location at 11:41, but not the subsequent 3 after. This result is different from the dataset I used from a different day, where all four locations in the dataframe appear.

Comment: Just for posterity, here's a link to the other dataset exported from the frame, https://www.dropbox.com/s/888rn0u6l89o5xr/data2.csv?dl=0, here's the visual, https://imgur.com/AJOhh0d, and the first four red candles occur at 9:42-45

Comment: @orion I think i get it: in the first set (8th April), you get only 1 time because the method catches only the first time of a period of 4 times red. In the second set (3rd of April) you get 4 times because there is actually 7 red candles in a row, so the first time 9:42 is returned because 9:42 to 9:45 are red, but 9:43 is returned because 9:43 to 9:46 are red, etc. does it makes sense?

Comment: Thanks! And yes it does make sense! Final question: would it be any easier to isolate and extract each 4 consecutive red candle segment (4 consecutive rows) rather than just the first? Would we use `rolling()` still?

Comment: @orion you could try something like `df['to_return'] = df['next_4days_red'].where(df['next_4days_red']).ffill(limit=3).fillna(0).astype(bool)` and then use this column in `df.loc...`, in the first case you would get the 4 times but in the second case the 7 times, it depends why do you it for after :)